# Sending attachment [logo image] in email - ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

could one kindly advise me how i attach a logo image using action mailer. i tried the below but i get an error

i get the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `attachments' for #<#<Class:0x007f84d2282400>:0x007f85714656d8>
mailers/mailer_report.rb
```

-

```
class MailerReport < ActionMailer::Base

  def report_advert(report)
    attachments.inline['img-logo-main.png'] = File.read('/images/img-logo-main.png')
    @report = report
    mail( to: "akunorbea@gmail.com",
          subject: "<Report> #{report.category_report.name} | #{report.advert.title}", 
          from: "<no-reply@africanjober.com>")
  end
end
```

views/mails_report/report_advert.html.erb

```
      <div style="color:#0000FF">Reported Advert: <%= @report.advert.title %></div>
        <%= image_tag attachments['img-logo-main.png'].url -%>
        Report Catgeory: <%= @report.category_report.name %><br/>
        Advert Catgeory: <%= @report.advert.category_advert.name %> / <%= @report.advert.category_advertskill.name %><br/>
        Advert link: <%= link_to "#{@report.advert.title}", userr_advert_url(@report.advert.userr, @report.advert) %>
      </div>
```

report_controller.rb

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json
  before_action :set_report, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    @report = Report.new(report_params)
    @report.save
    respond_to do |format|
      if @report.save
        MailerReport.report_advert(@report).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to(search_adverts_path, notice: 'Report was successfully sent.') }
        format.json { render json: @report, status: :created, location: @report }
      else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Cannot send report.'
        render :new
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `/images` will look for (in) a folder in the root of your server called images, I guess that's not what you want.  You need to specify the full path.  You can use `Rails.root` to get the root directory path for the application.  I don't get why you're getting undefined method attachments though.

Comment: Do you get that error in mailer or the view? Please post full stacktrace

Comment: @ARTLoe did you ever solve this? I'm having the same error even though I used the full path, `File.read(Rails.root.join("app/assets/images/#{image}"))`

Answer (score 0):

Try: `File.read('app/images/img-logo-main.png')`

Comment: Please, if this is really an answer then elaborate it.